# Remove duplicate on second column and keep the first entry in googlesheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a file that contains many columns and rows. I want to remove a duplicate entry in a certain column based on another column. I want to keep the first entry (if there is a duplicate) and erase the duplicates.

For example:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 31560 | 0 |
| 31560 | 0 |
| 30530 | 62.77 |
| 30530 | 62.77 |
| 30540 | 100 |

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 31560 | 0 |
| 31560 |  |
| 30530 | 62.77 |
| 30530 |  |
| 30540 | 100 |

I found the following code, but it just erases the duplicates and it is not based on a certain column.

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(COUNTIF($A2:A15,A2)=1,A2,""))
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN({A2:B, A2:A&B2:B}, 9^9, 2, 3, 0), 9^9, 2)
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IF(1=COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, B2:B, B2:B, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), B2:B, ))
```

[image]